# Non parametric one sample test on difference

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, nonparametric

I have a group which is not normally distributed. I need to check whether the difference between left and right hand within the group is significant. Initially, I calculated the absolute difference (I don't really care which one is better, I just need to check if the difference is significant) and then I did the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test but I am not sure that this is the right one to use.
If the group was normal I would have done a one sample t-test on the difference but now I am quite confused.

Please, could you please advise me which test is better to use?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Kolmogorov-Smirnov one-sample test on the absolute differences does not make much sense (what would be the reference distribution anyway).

Most prominent non-parametric alternative to the one-sample t-test on the differences $D_i$ is Wilcoxon's signed-rank test. It has never much lower power than the classic t-test but has less assumptions.

Other options include

- One-sample median test (checks the null hypothesis of a median difference of 0 through a binomial test)
- Permutation version of the one-sample t-test based on randomly switching signs of the differences

Comment: Note that this test may reject the null due to different variances and not means - it is a test on distribution not on mean

Answer (score 1):

[One-sample Wilcoxon test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test) may be what you are looking for.

It test if non-independent samples differ and it is non-parametric.

Nice tutorial with R is [here](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/one-sample-wilcoxon-signed-rank-test-in-r).